# Equivalent for markdown's `` in XeLaTex

Tags: xetex, code, markdown

Sometimes I want to cite stuff such as commands or library names etc etc. Over markdown I use the `somestuff` citation. But how I can do similar ting in tex?

Comment: `\texttt{command}` if there are no special characters, otherwise `\verb|command|` (the `|` is any character not appearing in `command`).

Comment: The `\texttt{command}` did the job 4 me!

Answer (score 1):

To complete @egreg's comment, you can use the `tcolorbox` package to obtain the required format.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\somestuffstyle}{on line,boxrule=0pt,boxsep=0pt,colback=lightgray,top=1pt,bottom=1pt,left=1pt,right=1pt,arc=0pt,fontupper=\ttfamily}
\begin{document}
\somestuffstyle{somestuff}
\end{document}
```